# Finding the CGRect of a view

Tags: swift3

I have a view which subclasses a collectionView horizontal. Each cell takes the full width and the full height. Within each cell, I have a button and I'm not able to find its proper location relative to my viewController's main view.

I have tried the following and many other combination but

```
 guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIds.studyCell, for: [0,1]) as? StudyCell else { return nil }

    transition.originFrame = self.view.convert(cell.explanationButton.frame, to: self.view.superview)
    transition.presenting = true
    return transition
  }
```

Comment: cell.convert(cell.explanationButton.frame, to: self.view) ?

Comment: hm i think it s still doing something weird

Comment: This was probably because the button was coming from a different cell, I changed it to the main view. Thanks